# Javascript Invalid Date to string format

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to parse time which is retrieved from MySql via jSon

something like:

```
new Date('12:15:24').toString('h:mmtt');
```

but I keep getting Invalid Date in console

What I need to do is convert 24 hour format into 12 hour am/pm and vice versa

Comment: parse the string yourself. No need for `Date()` to do this. Not hard to search how to get the string parts

Comment: Can you modify the server side code?

Comment: Yes, I could but rather then modifying php code which puls records from database, I thought it would be easier to do it on client side with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Date()` constructor only likes a very restricted set of date formats. If your input format is fixed at `'hh:mm:ss'` it is probably easier to format it using a simple string replace:

```js
function formatTime(time) {
  return time.replace(/(\d?\d)(:\d\d):(\d\d)/, function(_, h, m) {
    return (h > 12 ? h-12 : +h === 0 ? "12" : +h) + m + (h >= 12 ? "pm" : "am");
  });
}

console.log( formatTime('00:15:24') );
console.log( formatTime('09:15:24') );
console.log( formatTime('10:15:24') );
console.log( formatTime('11:15:24') );
console.log( formatTime('12:15:24') );
console.log( formatTime('13:15:24') );
console.log( formatTime('14:15:24') );
```

Further reading:

- [String `.replace()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)
- [Unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_())

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I would like to format time based on if statement. For example if 1 show 24 hour format else show 12 hour format. Everything else remains the same.

Comment: `(h > 12 ? h-12 : +h === 0 ? "12" : +h)` can be replaced with `(h%12 || 12)`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG - Nice one. (Originally I had just a single ternary  which didn't look too bad - till I realised I forgot about midnight, so then I just extended from there to get the ugly expression you quoted. Obviously your way is better.)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using date/time manipulation library, such as http://momentjs.com/ .

You can also achieve what you want by splitting the time string and creating a Date() object. Example:

```
var time = '12:15:24';
var timePortions = time.split(':');
new Date(0,0,0,timePortions[0], timePortions[1], timePortions[2])
```

This is not a safe way to manipulate date/time, though.

Comment: I was thinking of using moments or xDate, but for a such a simple task, I don't think it's worthed.

Answer (score 0):

it is better to use moment.js to handle datetime like this

```js
// get hours:minutes:seconds of the date 31-Jan_2016 9.31.21
console.log(moment('2016-01-31 09:30:21').format('HH:mm:ss'))

// get current hours:minutes:seconds
console.log(moment().format('HH:mm:ss')) 

// get current date-month-year hours:minutes:seconds
console.log(moment('2016-01-31 09:30:21').format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't at least one of your examples (if not all of them) include the OP's input format and desired output format?

Comment: Answers should not rely on a library that isn't tagged or noted in the OP.